# Question on the Proof of Renormalizability in Gauge Field Theory in Collins's *Renormalization*

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, renormalization

I am currently reading Collins's *Renormalization: An Introduction to Renormalization, the Renormalization Group and the Operator-Product Expansion*, and have reached Chapter 12. However, I am puzzled by the application of Eq. (12.2.14). If I understand correctly, Collins aims to prove that $\langle0|T\delta_R\psi(x)\bar{\psi}(y)\bar{c}^a(z)|0\rangle$ (after all subdivergences have been subtracted) is finite, and such argument relies on $\langle0|T\delta_R\psi(x)\bar{\psi}(y)\mathscr{B}_a^\mu(z)|0\rangle$ being finite. In other words, we need Theorem 4 on page 298 to hold for $\delta_R\psi$ (at least at the $N$ loop level). However, this has not been effectively proven. In subsection 12.2.9, I learned how to use a derivation similar to Eq. (12.2.12) to prove that the correlation function of $\mathscr{B}_{a\mu}$ with any number of basic fields is finite at the $N$ loop level. However, these arguments cannot be applied to $\langle0|T\delta_R\psi(x)\bar{\psi}(y)\mathscr{B}_a^\mu(z)|0\rangle$.

How can we prove that $\langle0|T\delta_R\psi(x)\bar{\psi}(y)\mathscr{B}_a^\mu(z)|0\rangle$ is finite?